# How to suppress a new line when using multline within enumerate?

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate, multline

I am using enumerate with some long equations. I am breaking the equations into multiple lines using \multline. Example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{multline*} m_1,m_2>0\implies{}f(m_1+m_2)= \underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1+m_2}= \\   \underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1}+\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_2}=f(m_1)+f(m_2)
    \end{multline*}
    \end{enumerate}
```

When I do this, the output looks like

[image]

I don't want the new line after the "1." What is the correct way to eliminate it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you switch from the displayed-math `multline*` environment to the (inline- or displayed-math `multlined` environment. `multlined` is an environment provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package.

You asked for a solution uses an equivalent of a two-row `multline*` environment. I think that a three-row `aligned` environment is actually more suitable than a two-row `multlined` environment is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item 
   $\begin{multlined}[t] 
   m_1,m_2>0\implies{}f(m_1+m_2)
     =\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1+m_2\text{ terms}} \\
     ={\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1\text{ terms}}}
     +{\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_2\text{ terms}}}
     =f(m_1)+f(m_2)
   \end{multlined}$
   \item 
   $\begin{aligned}[t] 
   m_1,m_2>0\implies f(m_1+m_2)
     &=\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1+m_2\text{ terms}} \\
     &={\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1\text{ terms}}}
      +{\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_2\text{ terms}}} \\
     &=f(m_1)+f(m_2)
   \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of [t]?

Comment: @Gary - `[t]` is for `top`-alignment, meaning that the *top* row in the math part aligns with the outside enumerate `\item`. The default is `[c]`, for vertical centering; the third option is `[b]`, for bottom alignment..

Answer (score 4):

Manually, for example, using

```
\abovedisplayskip=-1.25\baselineskip
```

[image]

---

See this MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}\abovedisplayskip=-1.25\baselineskip
\item \begin{multline*} m_1,m_2>0\implies{}f(m_1+m_2)= \underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1+m_2}= \\   \underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_1}+\underbrace{1_K+\ldots{}+1_K}_{m_2}=f(m_1)+f(m_2)
    \end{multline*}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To make your answer less dependent on the choice of the document's main font size, you could replace `\abovedisplayskip=-18pt` with `\abovedisplayskip=-1.25\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Mico  Approved the suggestion. :-)))))